# apache-arrow does not compile with typescript

Tags: typescript, apache-arrow

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955863/apache-arrow-ts-does-not-compile) for the `@apache-arrow/ts` library as well.

I've been able to get this to bundle with [webpack](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/9752), but I've been considering using `rollup` instead for other issues I'm having with my library.  However, that requires me to do a `tsc` first.

Is this an issue with my configuration or an issue with `apache-arrow`?

In my `package.json`:

```
"apache-arrow": "^3.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.3",
```

In one of my `.ts` files:

```
import { Table } from 'apache-arrow';
```

My output when running `tsc`:

```
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(47,466): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(47,641): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(48,471): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(48,646): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(62,352): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(62,527): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(63,353): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(63,528): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(64,353): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(64,528): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(65,353): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(65,528): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(66,354): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(66,529): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(67,354): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(67,529): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(68,355): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(68,530): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(69,355): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(69,530): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(70,360): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(70,535): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(71,357): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(71,532): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(72,358): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(72,533): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(73,358): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(73,533): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(74,358): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(74,533): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(75,359): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(75,534): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(76,359): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(76,534): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(77,360): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(77,535): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(78,360): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(78,535): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(79,365): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadValueResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.d.ts(79,540): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadDoneResult'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/interfaces.d.ts(178,5): error TS2502: '[Type.FixedSizeList]' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(46,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(51,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(53,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(53,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(57,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(57,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PipeOptions'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(58,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(59,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(61,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PipeOptions'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(61,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(62,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/interfaces.d.ts(88,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/stream.d.ts(5,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/stream.d.ts(7,91): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/stream.d.ts(30,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Response'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/stream.d.ts(30,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/whatwg/builder.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/whatwg/builder.d.ts(25,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/io/whatwg/builder.d.ts(26,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamDefaultController'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(19,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Response'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(19,82): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(62,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(71,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ByteLengthQueuingStrategy'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(74,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(75,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/reader.d.ts(236,5): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'schema' must be of type 'Schema<T>', but here has type 'Schema<any>'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/writer.d.ts(36,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'QueuingStrategy'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/writer.d.ts(42,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WritableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/writer.d.ts(43,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/ipc/writer.d.ts(65,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/recordbatch.d.ts(17,18): error TS2430: Interface 'RecordBatch<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'StructVector<T>'.
  The types of 'slice(...).clone' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '(data: Data<Struct<T>>, children?: AbstractVector<any>[]) => RecordBatch<T>' is not assignable to type '<R extends DataType<Type, any> = Struct<T>>(data: Data<R>, children?: AbstractVector<R>[]) => VectorType<R>'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
        Type 'Data<R>' is not assignable to type 'Data<Struct<T>>'.
          Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'Struct<T>'.
            Property 'dataTypes' is missing in type 'DataType<Type, any>' but required in type 'Struct<T>'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/recordbatch.d.ts(24,22): error TS2415: Class 'RecordBatch<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'StructVector<T>'.
node_modules/apache-arrow/util/buffer.d.ts(10,328): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStreamReadResult'.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I ran into the same issues with apache-arrow v6 and the only work around I found is to set `"skipLibCheck": true,` in the `tsconfig.json`. Additionally, I filed a bug report (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14933) hoping that they will fix the typing errors at some point.

Comment: Mine is working with 6, and I did not make any changes to my `tsconfig.json`.  4 and 5 however did not work.

Comment: See the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955863/apache-arrow-ts-does-not-compile. - someone put together a repo to verify this.

Comment: That person is me  and it shows that it's not working in v6 under strict type checking

Comment: Oh my - I see.  Well, thank you for putting that together.  Arrow has drastically improved since 3 to 6, but this scares me with the volatility of the TS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this problem is related to the TypeScript version: for me, it works fine with TS 4.0.2. But after updating to a later version, everything goes wrong. Maybe it will help.